# How can I generate apk file for create-react-native-app (using EXPO.IO component)

Tags: android, react-native, expo, create-react-native-app

I setup my app using create-react-native and I used **expo's** Video component in my app. How can I keep this video component and generate the apk file? Correct me if I'm wrong: to my understanding npm run eject prevents you from using expo components in the future. So how can I generate the apk file. It doesn't matter if it's signed or unsigned, atleast to me, I just want to email my friend the apk file so he can run it on his phone

Edit: This is not a duplicate of: [How can I generate an apk that can run without server with react-native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35935060/how-can-i-generate-an-apk-that-can-run-without-server-with-react-native)

As that question asks how to generate an apk file for react-native, mine ask how this works with the specific create-react-native-app build where I am using an expo component

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I generate an apk that can run without server with react-native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35935060/how-can-i-generate-an-apk-that-can-run-without-server-with-react-native)

Comment: @Mo'menMohamed I have edited my question to expand upon why this is not a duplicate and my specific needs with expo video component and create-react-native-app build

Comment: share the link to your friend using expo XDE https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/introduction/installation.html

Comment: maybe does this help https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

exp:build android
exp:status to check the status of your apk

will generate a url for you to download the apk from

Answer (score 6):

1. Install `npm install -g exp`
2. edit `app.json` file in our project

   ```
   {
   "expo": {
   "name":"my app",
   "icon":"./logo.png",
   "description":"some description about our project",
   "sdkVersion": "27.0.0",
   "android":{
        "package":"com.johncy.myapp",
         "versionCode":1 , 
         "icon":"./logo.png"
             }
            }
   }
   ```
3. give the command in our project directory `exp build:android`
4. Just wait for few mins.It will give an url for our build project.We can download `*.apk` file from that link.

Answer (score 5):

1. Install expo cli globally `npm install -g exp`
2. Run `exp build:android` or `exp build:ios` inside the project
3. Choose some expo options
4. Wait few minutes

A build link should be printed in the terminal. For the next steps see this thread: [Created an app with create-react-native-app, how to publish it to the Google Play Store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42967465/created-an-app-with-create-react-native-app-how-to-publish-it-to-the-google-pla)

Answer (score 2):

Android App Bundle(AAB): `expo build:android -t app-bundle`

Android Apk: `expo build:android -t apk`