# How to publish a react native as a apk file or ios file?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, mobile, react-native

I have been learning React Native for a while by watching video tutorials. The instructors are teaching how to code and run the project in simulator but no one ever mentioned or showed how to publish the local projects as a production app. I researched and checked official React Native documentation but I could not figure out how to publish

The question is how can I make a downloadable, installable single file mobile application to use in my mobile phone.

Please, share any useful video tutorial or documentation. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried this..?? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deploy/Publish Android app made with React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32783344/deploy-publish-android-app-made-with-react-native)

Comment: Maybe it is duplicated, but read [This Link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html), It is official facebook tutorial.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**ANDROID**

You must generate a private key by running

```
$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias my-key-alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Then you have to set the generated file `my-release-key.keystore` under `android/app` in your project.

Edit the file `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` as following

```
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE=my-release-key.keystore
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=my-key-alias
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=[YOUR PASSWORD]
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=[YOUR PASSWORD]
```

Now edit `android/app/build.gradle` as following:

```
android {
     ...
     defaultConfig { ... }
     signingConfigs {
         release {
             if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                 storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                 storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                 keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                 keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
             }
         }
     }
     buildTypes {
         release {
             ...
             signingConfig signingConfigs.release
         }
     } }
```

And in your terminal run `cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease`

Your APK will be generated inside this directory `android/app/build/outputs/apk/` as `app-release.apk`

To install it in your device, run: `react-native run-android --variant=release`

More info in the official docs: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html

**IOS**

You must have an Apple Developer Account https://developer.apple.com/account/

1. Open Xcode and sign in with your developer account
2. Build your project
3. From toolabar Select Product > Archive
4. Click on Validate
5. Click on Export
6. Download IPA file
7. From toolabar Click on Xcode > Open Developer Tool > Application Loader
8. Click on Deliver App
9. Select the downloaded IPA file
10. Wait a few minutes and your app will be available on iTunes Connect itunesconnect.apple.com
11. From there you can use Test Flight to distribute your app to a test team.
12. Download Test Flight App in your device
13. After you set up a test team, all testers will be available to download the app through Test Flight

More info here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You should generate a Signed APK file for android while publishing on Play store.

[Click here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html) to see full instruction of how to create signed APK file.

For iOS [Click here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html)