# React Native publication Android

Tags: android, react-native

I wrote a very nice application for personal use in React Native. I'm surprised I can't build it and run it on my phone. In ReactJS, this is done in one command, doesn't React Native have an easy way to do this? I've tried a lot already. I got the AAB file and tried running it with APKMirror Installer and other apps. This doesn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deploy/Publish Android app made with React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32783344/deploy-publish-android-app-made-with-react-native)

Comment: You should add more details.

Comment: No. The answer to this question did not help me. I don't want to publish the app on Google Play. I want to install it on my phone. Now I connect the phone to the computer using USB and start the application with the command "npx expo start --tunnel" (other commands do not start) but now the application is ready and I want to install it not on the phone, like other applications. In ReactJS, I run the "react-scripts build" command and I get a ready application folder. Can't I do the same in React Native?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using expo library, it will be very easy, all you need to do is scan qrcode when running it by

```
expo start
```

If you're using without expo which is bare project you need to create apk file using below command for Android

```
./gradlew assembleDebug   // apk file for debugging
./gradlew assembleRelease   // apk file production for preview purpose
./gradlew bundleRelease // aab file for production to upload on Play Store
```

Note: you need to copy all the file on your mobile or emulator to test it

Reference :

https://docs.expo.dev/

https://developer.android.com/build/building-cmdline

Comment: I want to run the application not for testing, for testing I run it using the "npx expo start --tunnel" command, other methods do not work for me. But now I want to install the finished application on my phone without publishing it on Google Play.

Comment: Create using eas build

Comment: It seems I have already done this and got the AAB file. But this file does not run on my Android device.

Comment: Build for apk use this command eas build -p android --profile preview, you can build aab, apk preview, apk development type using eas build

Comment: Thank you very much. Finally I managed to publish my application thanks to you. I have one more question. After the first publication, I decided to make corrections and publish again. But with each new publication, I get the same application as the first time.

Comment: Change your app version and build number, upload it on production on google dev console, play store will share only the newest version